# Настроить цикличный запуск

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.
Есть код:

```
package ru.copy;

public class workProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

//МОЙ код для копирования данных
 }
}
```

Моя программа копирует файлы из одной папки в другую. Дело в том, что в папку исходник будут периодически заливаться файлы, происходить это будет на протяжении 15-20 часов и нужно перекопировать ВСЕ файлы. Помимо того эти файлы в папке исходнике будут находится там 1 час, а затем удаляться(потому и нужно их от туда скопировать).

Как сделать постоянное выполнение кода и процедуру отключения?

Самое простое сделать вечный цикл:

```
public class workProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
int a = 1;
while (true) {

//МОЙ код для копирования данных
             }
 }
}
```

Тогда программа уходит в вечный цикл, работает и файлы копируются. Но как сделать корректную остановку такого кода?
Да и нет более аккуратного решения?

Да, пробовал запуск по интервалам времени:

```
   Timer timer = new Timer();
   TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
       //мой код
    }
   };

  timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, 10000);
  //первое число - когда он запуститься, второе - через сколько будет повторяться
```

Это некорректно, т.к. процедура может не успеть завершиться к нужному времени и запустится отдельный поток, что может привести к ошибке, да и опять же - как стопить такое?

P.S. наверное, по моей стилистике написания вы поняли, что я начинающий, потому очень прошу давать развёрнутые ответы с комментариями(я старался максимально понятно задать вопрос).

Comment: Проверяйте после копирования файла, если ли новые файлы для копирования, если нету, то останавливаете поток выполнения, если есть, то копируете файл и повторяете процедуру

Comment: Можно пример кода?

Comment: программа только копирует? почему вы пишете это на джаве?

Comment: Мне кажется это проще решить внешним скриптом через `cron job` или чем-то подобном

Comment: Смотрит в директорию, находит нужные файлы по маске, берёт первые десять, копирует,сразу удаляет их в папке исходнике, в папке получателе архивирует этот десяток файлов, затем удаляет скопированные файлы. Идёт на второй круг берёт следующие 10 файлов и по новой. Когда файлы кончатся она идёт в ДРУГУЮ папку исходник и делает тоже самое. Всего 4 папки исходника.
Делаю на java потому - что такая стоит задача.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю в данной ситуации (хотя конечно целиком её оценить не могу из-за недостаточности данных) можно сделать так: Создать ThreadPoolExecutor в который помещать задачи копирования одного файла в папку назначения. При этом ещё создать отдельный Thread где по маске ищутся файлы и для каждого найденного, но ещё не поставленного в виде очереди копирования в ThreadPoolExecutor создавать такую задачу, а уже поставленные в очередь или уже обработанные игнорировать (для этого можно завести потокобезопасный список Path элементов или что-то в этом роде). А сам ThreadPoolExecutor настроить оптимальным образом согласно производительности компьютера. Таким образом задача будет разбита на всего пару отдельных классов-потоков

- Поток ищущий новые файлы в директории источнике (делающий цикл поиска раз в несколько секунд/минут через вайт) и создающий для каждого нового найденного файла отдельную таску для пула
- Таски копирования файла с последующим удалением.

Ну и как всегда остановить программу можно при помощи шутдауна пула, и выставления флага интерапт у поискового потока